# Globally change Windows shortcut links

Tags: windows, shortcuts

Windows 7
My files (250 gigabytes) are in  C:\info

I have an external USB-based hard drive that is permanently mapped as M: drive.
Everything in C:\info is backed up to M:\info.

Within the C:\info file hierarchy I have hundreds of shortcuts in various directories that allow me to open a file in a different directory (within the C:\info hierarchy) without having to navigate to that different directory.

I want to be able to navigate within the M:\info hierarchy, including the 
shortcuts, when the USB hard drive is connected to a different computer.

The problem is that all of the shortcuts in the M:\info hierarchy, point to files in the C:\info hierarchy.

I want to write a command file (batch file) that changes all of the shortcuts in M:\info to point to the equivalent file in  M:\info.

If I do this manually it will take a very long time.

I thought that if I can dissect a Windows shortcut file I may be able to write a command file to globally change all of them.

But when I try to edit the Windows shortcut file, with a programmers 
editor such as UltraEdit, Windows 7 will not allow me to open the file.

UltraEdit reports "Access Denied". I tried running UltraEdit as Administrator but that did not work.

I have looked at posts here on this site that are either outdated or are for remote files on a LAN/WAN. I downloaded an app which claims to do exactly what I want but it is less than obvious, how to use the program, and the Help file (chm) file is blank.

Is there a way to globally change M:\info Windows shortcut links to point to m:\info rather than c:\info?

Many thanks !

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir . **However**, after editing, I find the .lnk file no longer works. It might be easier to use a third-party tool such as Clavier+ or AutoHotkey to copy and modify the old shortcuts.